# Exclude fields in Lucene query from Elasticsearch in Grafana table

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

In my Elasticsarch instance I have data stored that looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 25,
    "tasks": {
        "cleaning": "done",
        "lunch": "in progress"
    }
}
```

Every document has the `name`, `age` and `tasks` field but what fields exist in the `tasks` field varies between the documents. I want to visualize the data in a Grafana table which is why I have a query setup with the `Raw data` setting.

My Lucene  query at the moment is just "*" but I would like to exclude the `tasks` field in my query, such that the table looks like this:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 25 |
| Alice | 24 |
| ... | ... |

Using the `Organize Fields` Transformation won't work because as already stated the fields inside `tasks` vary.